# Rascal: String split function

Tags: string, split, separator, rascal

Is it possible to keep the literal separator while using split() on a string in rascal?

For example,

```
split("/*", line)
```

Comment: The split function does not have that feature, so you might have to write your own. To split strings I would recommend writing either a syntax definition or use regular expressions.

Comment: I have been able to create my own split function with regex and capture. This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: That's cool. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create my own split function. It is not perfect, but it seems to solve the issue that I was facing earlier.

```
public list[str] splitString(list[str] fileLines)
{
    list[str] splitList = [];

    for(line <- fileLines)
    {
        if( /^<x:.*>\/\*<y:.*>$/ := line)
        {
            splitList = splitList + x;
            splitList = splitList + "/*";
            splitList = splitList + y;
        }
        else if(/^<x:.*>\*\/<y:.*>$/ := line)
        {   
            splitList = splitList + x;
            splitList = splitList + "*/";
            splitList = splitList + y;
        }
        else
        {
            splitList = splitList + line;
        }
    }

    return splitList;
}
```